# Cordova app asking for push notification capability even though it's disabled

Tags: ios, cordova, apple-push-notifications

When looking at xcode's settings for my Cordova application, I can see that the command used to compile the app includes `-DDISABLE_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS=1`... which looks like it removes all push notification related code from the build.

In spite of that, Apple sent us a mail asking us to `make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal`, because apparently, we are using that API.

Considering `DISABLE_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS` is defined, I don't know how that's possible. I'm using Cordova 4.3.0, and the plugins device, dialogs, inappbrowser, network-information and splashscreen.

Comment: Which version or cordova are you using?

Comment: 4.3.0, I added it to the original post as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not using this version of Cordova (last time I used Cordova 3.6.0), but you should check if in your application delegate if one (or many) of the following methods is present:

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
  didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
  didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
  didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
  fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
  handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
  forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
  completionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
  didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo

If so, you may:

- delete it/them
- suround them with a #ifndef DISABLE_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS ... #endif (you should also check that in your main project, not only on the sub cordova one, the -DDISABLE_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS is set)

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you added a plugin that requires the usage of push notifications (for example, but not only, `cordova-plugin-mfp-push` ) so even if Push Notifications is off in your project, it still shows as required.
Or you may just have to refresh the Xcode entitlements by turning on and off the Push Notifications capability.